# Use intermediate layer values to fit model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to train an autoencoder whose input is some dense features concatenated with the output of an embedding layer. I therefore want to use the output of the concatenation layer for both the input and the labels to train the autoencoder:

```
# Inputs
dense = Input(shape=(train_dense_scaled.shape[1],))
sequences = Input(shape=(train_embed.shape[1],))

# Embedding layer
embed = Embedding(vocab_size, 20, input_length=num_embed_cols)(sequences)
flatten = Flatten()(embed)

ae_input = concatenate([dense, flatten])    

# Autoencoder
e_128 = Dense(units=128, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=initializer)(ae_input)
e_64 = Dense(units=64, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=initializer)(e_128)
decoded = Dense(units=128, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=initializer)(e_64)

model = Model(inputs=[sequences,dense], outputs=decoded)
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(x=[train_dense_scaled,train_embed], y=ae_input, epochs=200, batch_size=128)
```

I get the following error

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-f29037b9f7ab> in <module>()
---> 50 model.fit(x=[train_dense_scaled,train_embed], y=ae_inputs, epochs=200, batch_size=128)
...
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

The output of the concatenation layer `ae_input` is the input into the autoencoder, and thus what I want to use as labels to train the model. I'm assuming this is where I'm going wrong and not properly feeding the output of this intermediate layer to the `model.fit()` method.

Comment: what is `train_dense`, `train_embed` and `ae_input`?

Comment: `train_dense_scaled` and `train_embed` are the training data matrices. `ae_input` is the concatenation layer as described above.

Comment: Are they all numpy arrays? It could look like one of them are Tensor objects.

Comment: That is sort of the point. Instead of the usual way of feeding the graph numpy arrays, I am wondering if it is possible to use the output of an intermediate layer (a tensor) to fit the model.